# Using Google Maps API keys after trial period

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-console-developer

I'm just singed in to Google Developers Console in order to get API Keys for Google Maps Framework which I'm using while developing iOS Application.

GMSServices.provideAPIKey("SOMEKEY")

So, the question: will I be able to use API key after expiring of trial period. If not - is there any way to use Google Maps SDK for iOS for free without a key?

Answer (score 0):

iOS key is free. It even say is in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#step_5_get_an_ios_api_key):

> Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's API usage,
>   and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if
>   necessary. The key is **free**, you can use it with any of your
>   applications that call the Google Maps SDK for iOS, and it supports an
>   unlimited number of users. You obtain an API key from the Google
>   Developers Console by providing your application's bundle identifier.